# Can't boot Ubuntu after hard reset. (GRUB issues)

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot

I have a laptop with both Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 installed.  Windows crashed, and I have to get a repair disk for it, so in the meantime, I'm using Ubuntu, however when I went to boot Ubuntu I got a GRUB interface.  If I command `boot` it just tells me I need to load the kernel first. This is my last option, is there any way I can fix this and just get Ubuntu back?

I'll mention here that this happened after I was forced to do a hard reset on the machine.

It may actually be 12.10, but I'm not positive.

Comment: Normally, you dont have to give any command during boot process. Select, Ubuntu from the list and just press enter.

Comment: use a live boot ubuntu, go to shell and fsck all partitions to see if there is an error and give us the output.

Comment: This sounds like a Wubi install (inside Windows). If this is the case, you need a Windows repair disk so you can run `chkdsk /f`.

Comment: >>This sounds like a Wubi install (inside Windows). If this is the case, you need a Windows repair disk so you can run chkdsk /f.<<     This is the case.  I am trying really hard not to lose my files.  Does anyone know if i can reinstall windows without erasing my harddrive?

Answer (score 0):

Grab some live CD or live USB with any Ubuntu taste or version, and repair your GRUB running it. This link can help: [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows).

Comment: I got everything working, but i was just booting under the option "Try it without installing".  This worked but it was a pain having to reinstall anything i got from the app center.  I installed Ubuntu to a partition on the hard drive.  Only now, that i restarted the computer, i'm back to the same problem. i'm attempting to make a fresh boot disc and see what happens.

Comment: ok, so now when i try to boot from the flash drive, it just takes me to the boot windows or the broken Ubuntu menu rather than the "install, try Ubuntu" screen.  I am getting really aggrivated at this point.  I cant even format the drive or read the contents on another computer.

Comment: The answers in the links above don't help you at all?